# Это ajax запрос или нет? Если да то как создать ответ типа успешно или ошибка и вывести на страницу?

Tags: php, laravel

```
$('.addNewGameBtnInModal').click(function (event) {
        var game_name = $('#game_name').val();
        var id_developer = $('#id_developer').val();
        var game_desc = $('#game_desc').val();
        var game_poster = $('#game_poster').val();
        var game_poster_mini = $('#game_poster_mini').val();

        $.post('games', {
            'game_name': game_name,
            'id_developer': id_developer,
            'game_desc': game_desc,
            'game_poster': game_poster,
            'game_poster_mini': game_poster_mini
        }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода который использую, в проекте с laravel. В data при post, delete, put нужно также добавлять токен.
Пример

```
data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        }
```

Ajax запрос

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST', // тип запроса 
                    url: '/url', // урл
                    data: data // данные в json
                    dataType: 'json', //тип данных 

                    beforeSend: function () {
                        // до отправки данных, можно поставить например гифку loading  
                    },

                    success: function (data) {
                        // При успешном запросе, показываем что успешно 
                    },

                    error: function (data) {
                       // если ошибка, показываем ошибку 
                    },

                    complete: function () {
                        // после завершения запроса, с любым исходом. Убираем гифку загрузки
                    }
                });
```

Comment: тегами form обносить поля обязательно? ибо в моем варианте необязательно но не работает добавление картинок на сервер, задолбался бороться

Comment: с form разобрался, теперь крч оно почему то презагружает страницу, но ведь такого не должно быть ведь так?

Comment: Нет, страницу не должно обновлять. Запрос проходит? ошибок в консоли нет? что возвращает back end?

Comment: public function store(Request $request)  
    {  
        $game = new Games;  
        $game->game_name = $request->game_name;  
        $game->id_developer = $request->id_developer;  
        $game->game_desc = $request->game_desc;  
        $game->steam_link = $request->steam_link;  
  
        if ($request->hasFile('game_poster')) {  
здесь загрузка картинки  
        }  
  
        if ($request->hasFile('game_poster_mini')) {  
здесь загрузка картинки  
        }  

        $game->save();  
        return response()->json(['success'=>'data']);  
    }

Comment: с back end все нормально. 
а как указан url? если роут, например main, то урл будет /main

Comment: url /games роут /dashoboard/games

Comment: я указал /dashoboard/games  всё равно релоад

Comment: панели разработчика f12 на вкладке console ошибок нет?

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/games 419 (unknown status)
случилась ошибка
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/games".

Comment: ошибка в скрипте, а именно data, передаете объект?
если объект тогда для сабмита формы можно реализовать так
$('form').submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/bin',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',

Comment: я передаю данные такого вида " 'game_name': game_name, " через data, var game_name = $('#game_name').val();

Comment: Из всех переменных сделайте, один json объект и передавайте его в запросе, так будет правильнее, back end получите json объект,
пример: data: ({game_name: game_name, id_developer: id_developer}),

Comment: var $game = {'game_name': game_name, ...} так сделал, релоад с*****

Comment: Если кнопка с классом `addNewGameBtnInModal` внутри `form`, то дайте ей `type="button"`, что бы она не сабмитила. Или делайте `event.preventDefault();` и `event.stopPropagation();` внутри вашего JS кода.